# how to transfer variable between 2 pages in javascript (Node)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'd like to transmit a variable to another page with Node, in order to use it in the other page, I tried localstorage and defining a global variable, but no result for the moment, it says that node can't access the localstorage of the window :

test.js

```js
var express = require('express')
var session = require('express-session')
var app = express()
 
app.post('/test1.html', function(req, res){
    var user = "Jonhy DEEPPP";
    console.log(user);
    res.render( 'test1.html', { user:user } );
});
```

test1.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Titre</title>
    </head>
 
    <body>
     
    <script>
     
alert(user);
    </script>
     
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your question is a bit mixed up I'm afraid. It's true, Node.js doesn't have access to the browser's `localStorage` because Node.js isn't running in the browser, it's running on the server (when used for a web project). If you want to send data from the JavaScript code running in the page on the browser to the JavaScript code running in Node.js on the server, send it via ajax. If you want to send data from Node.js to the browser, send it as part of the reply to an ajax or page request.

Comment: You should look into sessions in order to persist data related to each user that sends a request from a browser to your `Node` server - plenty of tutorials on the web about this, https://codeforgeek.com/manage-session-using-node-js-express-4/

Comment: thanks for your comments, i think i am going to look ajax because it corresponds to what i want, and i am definitely gonna check the link about sessions